# calculate the difference between two array

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP, how can I compare two array and get result in a third array ?

This result must contain old and new values. The goal is to display an HTML table with a header like  "field | old value | new value" as this, the user can compare all values one by one.

First array :

```
$array1 = array(
  'key1' => array(
    'key1.1' => 'value',
    'key1.2' => 'value',
  ),
  'key2' => array(
    'key2.1' => 'value',
    'key2.2' => 'value',
  ),
  'key3' => array(
    array('key3.1' => 'value'),
    array('key3.2' => 'value'),
  ),
);
```

Second array :

```
$array2 = array(
  'key1' => array(
    'key1.1' => 'value',
    'key1.2' => 'value',
  ),
  'key2' => array(
    'key2.1' => 'value',
    'key2.2' => 'value',
  ),
  'key3' => array(
    array('key3.1' => 'value'),
    array('key3.2' => 'value'),
  ),
);
```

What I expect :

```
$results = array(
  'key1' => array(
    'key1.1' => array(
      'old' => 'old_value',
      'new' => 'new_value',
    ),
    'key1.2' => array(
      'old' => 'old_value',
      'new' => 'new_value',
    ),
  ),
  'key2' => array(
    'key2.1' => array(
      'old' => 'old_value',
      'new' => 'new_value',
    ),
    'key2.2' => array(
      'old' => 'old_value',
      'new' => 'new_value',
    ),
  ),
  'key3' => array(
    array(
      'key3.1' => array(
        'old' => 'old_value',
        'new' => 'new_value')
    ),
    array(
      'key3.1' => array(
        'old' => 'old_value',
        'new' => 'new_value'),
    )
  ),
);
```

What I have already tried without success :

```
function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2) {

  $exclude = array(
    'custom_key'
  );

  $difference = array();
  foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)){
      if( !isset($array2[$key]) || !is_array($array2[$key]) ) {
        if(!in_array($key,$exclude)){
          $difference[$key]['old'] = $value;
          $difference[$key]['new'] = $array2[$key];
        }
      } else {
        $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
        if(!empty($new_diff))
          $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
      }
    } else if(!array_key_exists($key,$array2) || $array2[$key] !== $value) {
      if(!in_array($key,$exclude)){
        $difference[$key]['old'] = $value;
        $difference[$key]['new'] = $array2[$key];
      }
    }
  }
  return $difference;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: `array_merge_recursive` gets  almost what you want only 0 and 1 instead of old and new

Comment: I edited my first post to add more array example and the function that I tried without getting what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, i'm sure this will work for you

```
 <?php 
echo "<pre>";
$array1 = array(
  'key1' => array(
    'key1.1' => 'aaa',
    'key1.2' => 'xxx',
    'key1.3' => 'vvv',
  ),
  'key2' => array(
    'key2.1' => 'eee',
    'key2.2' => 'fff',
    'key2.3' => 'ggg',
  ),
) ;
echo "Array 1: </br>";
print_r($array1);

$array2 = array(
  'key1' => array(
    'key1.1' => 'aaa',
    'key1.2' => 'ddd',
    'key1.3' => 'ccc',
  ),
  'key2' => array(
    'key2.1' => 'hhh',
    'key2.2' => 'fff',
    'key2.3' => 'ttt',
  ),
); 
echo "Array 2:</br>";
print_r($array2);

$result='';
foreach($array1 as $key=> $val)
{
    foreach($val as $k=> $v)
    {
        if($v != $array2[$key][$k])
        {
            $result[$key][$k]['old']= $array2[$key][$k] ;
            $result[$key][$k]['new']= $v;
        }       
    }
}
echo "Compared Result: </br>";
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
?>
```

This will Output

```
Array 1: 
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [key1.1] => aaa
            [key1.2] => xxx
            [key1.3] => vvv
        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [key2.1] => eee
            [key2.2] => fff
            [key2.3] => ggg
        )

)
Array 2:
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [key1.1] => aaa
            [key1.2] => ddd
            [key1.3] => ccc
        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [key2.1] => hhh
            [key2.2] => fff
            [key2.3] => ttt
        )

)
Compared Result: 

Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [key1.2] => Array
                (
                    [old] => ddd
                    [new] => xxx
                )

            [key1.3] => Array
                (
                    [old] => ccc
                    [new] => vvv
                )

        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [key2.1] => Array
                (
                    [old] => hhh
                    [new] => eee
                )

            [key2.3] => Array
                (
                    [old] => ttt
                    [new] => ggg
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Perfect :) I just added a condition to get more depth in array dimension  if(is_array($v))

Comment: Thanks for appreciation !!

Answer (score 1):

Prepare arrays using array_walk_recursive, and combine them. Please note that the original arrays will be changed

```
array_walk_recursive($array1, function(&$i) { if(!is_array($i)) $i = array('old'=> $i); });
array_walk_recursive($array2, function(&$i) { if(!is_array($i)) $i = array('new'=> $i); });

print_r(array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2));
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/528080)

Comment: If original arrays are changed this is not a problem I'm not required to save the change. But as array_merge_recursive() your example doesn't run if I add 'key3' => array(array('key3.1' => 'value'),array('key3.2' => 'value'),), in original array...

Comment: yes, that changes the array structure, the code will not work

Comment: So what is better ? Convert the third key before the call of the array merge or add a condition in the array merge ?

Comment: i would prefer the fisrt